# How can the execute-around-pointer code invoke an operator->() twice, although I only dereference once?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, dereference, execute-around-pointer

Consider the following code, lifted from [this page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Execute-Around_Pointer#Execute-Around_Pointer) regarding the "execute around pointer" idiom":

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;

class VisualizableVector {
  public:
    class proxy {
      public:
        proxy (vector<int> *v) : vect (v) {
          std::cout << "Before size is: " << vect->size () << '\n';
        }
        vector<int> * operator -> () {
          std::cout << "Operator ->* invoked on proxy\n";
          // std::cout << std::stacktrace::current() << '\n';
          return vect;
        }
        ~proxy () {
          std::cout << "After size is: " << vect->size () << '\n';
        }
      private:
        vector <int> * vect;
    };
    VisualizableVector (vector<int> *v) : vect(v) {}    
    proxy operator -> () {
       std::cout << "operator->() invoked on the VisualizableVector\n";
       return proxy (vect);
    }
  private:
    vector <int> * vect;
};

int main()
{
  vector<int> vec;
  VisualizableVector vecc(&vec);
  vecc->push_back(10);
}
```

This [results](https://godbolt.org/z/faEEd1fve) (GodBolt.org) in:

```
operator->() invoked on the VisualizableVector
Before size is: 0
Operator ->* invoked on proxy
After size is: 1
```

How come an `operator->()` is executed twice, even though I only dereferenced once? Is a pointer supposed to be dereferenced repeatedly until the result is of a non-pointer type, or a non-dereferenceable type?

Comment: operator -> is recursive until it hits a non arrowable type (does not have an operator ->)

Comment: " Is a pointer supposed to be dereferenced repeatedly until the result is of a non-pointer type" yes https://stackoverflow.com/a/4421719/4117728

Comment: i remember to have read about this on cppref. Now I only find https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Restrictions. Somewhat weird that they mention it only under "restrictions"

Comment: Recursive `operator->` is like finding a surprising easter egg in the C++ language.

Comment: See [over.match.oper](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.oper) and the footnote about `->`.

Comment: C++ is for adventurous, hard to find part of it without bear traps and easter eggs.

Comment: @NathanOliver: That is at the same time amazing and scary.

Comment: @einpoklum I'm not sure about it being scary.  We wouldn't be able to use smart pointers like regular pointers if C++ didn't work this way, which I think was part of the motivation to have the ability.  Do note that `.` does not have this behavior so you can get rid of this effect by using `(*var_name).member_name`